# Unable to dynamically set the height of a Kendo grid under iOS

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following code to dynamically set the height of a Kendo MVC grid:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
$("#grid").css("height", 500);
grid.resize();
grid.redraw();
```

This works as expected in any Windows browser. However, it does not work in Chrome or Safari running on an iOS device.

Or perhaps there is a better way to dynamically change the height of the grid after initialization?

Comment: How about `css("height", "500px")` or `height(500)`?

Comment: @GaloisGirl - Thank you for the suggestion but neither worked.